# How can I quiet or suppress the "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" message when using an SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

There is a process running that occasionally accesses a port that I've tunneled through an SSH connection. These messages can be really obtrusive at times, so I am looking for a way to disable them.

Comment: this is a duplicate of 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210211/disable-ssh-tunnel-open-failed-messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try the ssh **-E** option and redirect debug logs towards `/dev/null` ?

```
ssh -E /dev/null <server>
```

Extract from `man ssh`:

```
     -E log_file
         Append debug logs to log_file instead of standard error.
```